# autosize/resize UIPickerView for each screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, resize, uipickerview, size-classes

I'm trying to adapte the size of my UIPickerView, and the content inside, I have resize the height of the picker view:

```
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 100)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 200)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 200)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 250)
    } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300)
    }

    //        pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    self.pickerView = pickerView
```

[image]

But now I want to resize the content inside, the height of each row, the size of the text, and do multiline if the content is too long, but I don't know how to do.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet var tfProjet: UITextField!
var pvProjetData = ["-Choisir-", "Rachat de crédits", "Renégociation de crédits"]
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 100)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 200)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 200)
    } else if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 250)
    } else if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300)
    }

    //        pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    self.pickerView = pickerView

    tfProjet.inputView = pickerView
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}


func selectRow(row: Int, inComponent component: Int, animated: Bool){

}

func updatePicker(){
    self.pickerView!.reloadAllComponents()
    pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if tfProjet.isFirstResponder(){
        return pvProjetData.count
    }
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if tfProjet.isFirstResponder(){
        return pvProjetData[row]
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if tfProjet.isFirstResponder(){
        let itemselected = pvProjetData[row]
        tfProjet.text = itemselected
        self.tfProjet.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget doing that by code, use autolayout. Auytolayout is indepentent from device.

Comment: I'm using code because if I put a picker view, it shows a bloc, but I wan't something when you click on a picker view appears

Comment: More over, use stacklayout and just set hidden attribute to your picker view. Example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50568393/pickerSample.zip